# Identify an attacker's web vulnerability scanner by IP request rate

Tags: penetration-test

When conducting a penetration test, I run into difficulties because the defense system can identify an attack due to the high rate of requests, and then block the IP address

Is there a way to avoid this detection?

Comment: There is a reason large-scale penetration tests cost lots of $$ - they require tons of IP addresses to match the size of a decent botnet, and those cost $$.

Answer (score 2):

Configure your vulnerability scanner to wait between requests or ask your customer to whitelist your IP knowing the fact that you have probed that this countermeasure is being effective.

Answer (score 0):

Why should avoid detection? Isn't this part of a good pentest as well? If the system you're auditing is set-up correctly it should be detecting your probe attempts! And even better if it's banning your IP from doing too much of that.

IMHO you shouldn't do whitelisting, as that is not the 'regular' way the system behaves. If it's not possible to do proper scanning on a host because of it's IDS/firewall, than it's 1-0 for the sysadmin who configured that machine/network.

It is all about the scope of your audit. If it's a black-box pen test, or a blue/red team set-up, you never should change those parameters, because you want this to be realistic as possible. A real hacker's IP won't be whitelisted, so why should yours?

On the other hand, if a customer asks to pen test a specific service or server, than it's feasible to have unfiltered access to that box. But in that situation it's more common to do a scan from the 'inside' (so you don't make the customer vulnerable), probably on a test/acceptance box, by sitting at the customers office or by VPN-ing to it. Also then it's more common to get an user account on such a system, to be able to logon to the server or application, so your pen test can be really thorough.